# An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Tags: c#, .net, xml, out-of-memory, xmldocument

I have the following code:

```
XmlTextReader DBLPReader = new XmlTextReader("dblp.xml");

// Load the source of the XML file into an XmlDocument
XmlDocument DBLPDoc = new XmlDocument();

// Load the source XML file into the first document
DBLPDoc.Load(DBLPReader);

// Close the reader
DBLPReader.Close();`
```

where `dblp` has around 800 MB.

I got an error that says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Xml.dll"

What is the solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, your solution could be:

- Use a SAX parser.
- Use a 64-bit machine.
- Don't attempt to load such a large file.
- Make the file smaller (e.g. eliminate whitespace or comments, shorten tag names).
- Catch the exception and handle it properly.

Comment: SAX isn't necessarily better than DOM by itself. There are tradeoffs in using one style of XML parsing over the other. That said, SAX-style parsers tend to be much quicker and more lightweight (if a little more complex to use).

Comment: SAX might be better in this scenario because you can avoid all the memory overhead of the DOM (which is clearly the problem) and store only the data you need to extract from the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be messing around with XML files of that size, you should probably consider using [System.Xml.XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx). There's a list of what it'll get you [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfz3cz6w%28VS.71%29.aspx), and a decent tutorial on how to use it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548).

Comment: Actually .. I am using XMLTextReader as you can see but is there other way of my coding that I can use XMLTextReader that could help.. regards

Comment: @Dena, only use a XmlReader/XmlTextReader, never load it into a XmlDocument.

Comment: Thanks @Simon -- That's what I meant. @Dena: XmlDocument reads the entire XML file and builds a DOM tree in memory that you can code against. Even if you figure that they've got some ridiculously efficient memory overhead that it's still going to be at least as big as the original file (which is probably being pretty generous). I would start with the tutorial that I mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

Run on a 64-bit machine and do set your build properties to target an x64 platform.